# how to construct git diff query in python

Tags: python, git

I'm using the recommended [GitPython module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/), 
but I cannot figure out how to construct the following command:

```
git diff --name-status ec04352 b945e6c
```

I would like to get information about all modified files between two commits, and this command does exactly what I want to do. Could you comment on it?

Answer (score 6):

This is one way to do it:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo('path/to/your/repo')
print repo.git.diff('ec04352', 'b945e6c', **{'name-status': True})
```

It is, however, going through the backdoor.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
a = repo.commit('ec04352')
b = repo.commit('b945e6c')
diffs = a.diff(b)

>>> a
<git.Commit "ec04352">
>>> b
<git.Commit "b945e6c">
>>> print diffs[0]
zip/JSONzip.java
=======================================================
lhs: 100644 | d8e3ac652a5a5158692fa5fc131340c03dffd08e
rhs: 100644 | 220686de3dcb0dd17a54cbc5f8e44df261b664d5
>>>
```

You'll need to play with the `Diff` object to figure out the difference.

Answer (score 2):

See [Obtaining Diff Information](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#obtaining-diff-information) in the GitPython manual for a few example on how to get the diff information between two commits.

```
hcommit = repo.head.commit
idiff = hcommit.diff()          # diff tree against index
tdiff = hcommit.diff('HEAD~1')  # diff tree against previous tree
wdiff = hcommit.diff(None)      # diff tree against working tree
```

These commands return a [DiffIndex](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=diffindex#git.diff.DiffIndex), which contain `iter_change_type` which you can call with each of the four different change types (`'A', 'D', 'R', 'M'`) to get the paths that have been changed (added, deleted, renamed, modified).